# If statment in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

Hy! Could someone help me out with this equation ? I looked onlyne for some solution but nothing could work :/

I am trying to figure it out how to calculate the following:

if anexe ( temporary higher work hours ) is greater  then the contract hours, are equal to anex - worker hours( which i called uren )
I want so calculate a if statement more or less like this:

If Anexe > contract, is equal to Anex - uren

else Anexe < contract then contract - uren

Thank you for helping out already!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  We use Excel tag only for questions on programming against Excel objects or files, or complex formula development. You may combine the Excel tag with VBA, VSTO, C#, VB.NET, PowerShell, OLE automation, and other programming related tags and questions if applicable. General help regarding Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User (http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

Above is a sample copy of your table with some random values between 0 and 100 filled in. I think the formula you want in cell D2 is:

```
=IF(C2>A2,C2-B2, IF(C2<=A2,A2-B2,0))
```

You can then copy it down to the cells below.

Comment: Thank you very much! now I will put in practice :D

Comment: you really only need `=IF(C2>A2,C2-B2,A2-B2)`  Because if they are equal it does not matter from which B2 is subtracted.

Comment: John, No need to thank answers on this forum. See https://stackoverflow.com/tour for the protocol.